# Click event position (Y) is too high

Tags: javascript, events, canvas, click, position

I have a canvas element and when i click on it i get the click position with e.clientX(Y) or e.screenX(Y). Something strange is happening. Y value is always too high. Please look at this image: http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/268/eventq.jpg. Any ideia why is it so high?

Comment: Is the canvas element the first/top element on the page?  The screenshot doesn't let us see the top of the page.  ClientY is not relative to the current element, but the page (viewport) itself.

Comment: No there are some texts... Is there a way to get it relative to the canvas element?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take the ClientX and Y and subtract the position of the canvas from them.

This example is unnecessarily verbose, just to show the steps:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var canvasX, canvasY;

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    canvasX = canvas.offsetLeft;
    canvasY = canvas.offsetTop;
    var eventX = event.clientX;
    var eventY = event.clientY;
    var relX = eventX - canvasX;
    var relY = eventY - canvasY;
    alert('X = ' + relX + ', Y = ' + relY);
});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/JfhJF/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can tell what's happening. You do not have the coordinates relative to your canvas, but relative to your viewport. It also depends on your browser whether or not they include padding.

Convert them to normal coordinates. In your case this involves substracting the offset of the canvas.